# How to merge multiple spreadsheets into 1 with app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a folder of spreadsheets (all the same format/ headings) and I need to create on big spreadsheet of all the data.

I was using:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("my folder id");
  
  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  
  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");
  
  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {


    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

    /* Open the spreadsheet */
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

    /* Get all its sheets */
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {
  
      /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
    }
  }      
}
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1ZVM2cHA24EZF5eZ8NqCkpN63C4iA1eAOR6AqZJRg98g.
> myFunction  @ Code.gs:24

Please could anyone help me??

Comment: Does the id in the error message belongs to the big spreadsheet? How many sheets do you will put into the big spreadsheet? How many cells in total will have the be big spreadsheet? Have you tried to execute your script in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works flawlessly when it is used for a couple of **lightweight** spreadsheet files.

The error you are getting has to do with the heavy size of the individual sheets you are trying to copy and also the fact that you are **iteratively increasing** the size of the `Merged Sheets` file. The files are heavy and as a result the script times out with this error.

The solution for now would be to reduce the data size of every spreadsheet to the absolute minimum.